# Python Subprocess in Multiple Terminals in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, subprocess, popen

I'm using Python's `subprocess` to spawn new processes. The processes are independent of each other and output some of the data related to the account creation.

```
for token in userToken:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python3','create_account.py',token)
            sleep(1)
```

I'm trying to find a way to get the output of each of the Python scripts to run in the separate VSCode terminals to clearly see how the processes are running.

For example, in VSCode you can split the terminals as in the screenshot below. It would be great if each of the processes would have its own terminal window.

[image]

I've also checked that you can run tasks in VSCode in separate terminals as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_task-output-support-split-terminals). Is there a way to launch multiple `subprocess` threads in separate terminals like that?

If that's not possible, is there another way I can run `subprocess` in multiple terminals in VSCode?

Comment: Do you want to run two sub-processes synchronously or asynchronously run the sub-processes in two terminals separately?

Comment: Hey @JillCheng, my processes are independent of each other and I'd like them to run asynchronously. They are not supposed to run in sequential order. Yes, I would like them to run in each terminal separately.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in VS Code, it supports running python code in a single thread in the terminal by default.

If you want to run the python code in two or more VS Code terminals separately, and not run them sequentially, you could manually enter the run command in the two VS Code terminals, for example:
The command to run the python file'c.py': "`..:/.../python.exe ..:/.../c.py`".

And for multi-threaded synchronous operation, except for the manual input of execution commands in two or more newly created terminals to make the code run synchronously, VSCode currently does not have other local support that supports this function.

I have submitted an application for this feature in Github and we are looking forward to the realization of this feature:

Github link: [Can VSCode automatically run python scripts in two or more terminals at the same time?](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14094)